# Expansion for non repeated parameter when creating a generic Form function

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

I am trying to create a function which takes a variable number of arguments and outputs a Form which maps each argument to a `nonEmptyText`.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Mapping on the args to create a dynamic tuple (gave multiple compiler errors):

   ```
   def formBuilder(args: String*): Form[_] = {
     Form(
       tuple(
         args.map(arg => arg -> nonEmptyText):_*
       )
     )
   }
   ```
2. Creating a list of singles  by mapping on the args (gives `Expansion for non repeated parameter` error):

   ```
   def formBuilder(args: String*): Form[_] = {
     Form(
       list(
         args.map(arg => single(arg -> nonEmptyText)): _*
       )
     )
   }
   ```

My use case is that I am building a frontend search page which contains a different set of fields based on a parameter, `name`. Previously, I did not need to make a form for this as all fields for any search were optional, but I have just received some business rules which state that certain `name`s have specific form rules. Therefore, when I do a `.bindFromRequest()` in my controller on this Form, I need to use the data from these now-validated Forms to display form errors if the forms are filled out incorrectly (compared to previously where I didn't bother validating the forms as every field was optional).

I hope that makes sense. Let me know if I can clarify any further. Anyway, here is the full implementation of what I have got so far to hopefully explain my problem further:

```
def searchForm(name: String, args: String*): Form[_] = {
  name.toUpperCase() match {
    case NAME_1 => Form(
      tuple(
        NAME_1_FIELD_1 -> nonEmptyText,
        NAME_1_FIELD_2 -> nonEmptyText
      )
    )
    case NAME_2 => Form(
      tuple(
        NAME_2_FIELD_1 -> nonEmptyText,
        NAME_2_FIELD_2 -> optional(text),
        NAME_2_FIELD_3 -> optional(text)
      ).verifying("HELP YOU FAILED", _ match {
        case (_, Some(_), _) | (_, _, Some(_)) => true
        case _ => false
      })
    )
    case _ => formBuilder(args: _*)
  }
}

def formBuilder(args: String*): Form[_] = {
  Form(
    list(
      args.map(arg => single(arg -> optional(text))): _*
    )
  )
}
```

This is how I wish to call my Form checker function from my controller:

```
searchForm(name, Seq("val1", "val2", "val3")).bindFromRequest().fold(
  // redirect back to previous page with form error warnings  
  formWithErrors => Future.successful(Redirect(.....))),
  // do something with the valid form
  formWithoutErrors => {
    .....
  }
)
```

I've been working on this for a few hours now with little luck. How do I successfully create Forms with variable arguments?

Comment: Hey James. 
What about catching the missing fields in the frontend using required fields? You could let the browser check whether everything is filled out. If fields were empty (or not fulfilling other conditions), the submit would just be disabled. Does this address your question / requirements?
Cheers
Jens

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in an elegant way. A Tuple contains a fixed number of elements of arbitrary types. A List contains a variable number of elements of the same type (or common super type). What you want is essentially converting a list to a tuple.

If you know the maximum number of elements in the tuple (and it is not too big), you can write a match with one case for each possible number of elements.

The number of elements in a tuple is limited to a small value (may be 22).